# Evolution shows wrong subject and sender in email list

Tags: email, evolution

My email provider recently had a disk problem. They finally got all the email restored a few days ago, but since that time, evolution's email list has gone wrong. If I click on a particular message to read it, a different message opens. This does not effect emails that have arrived today, but does effect some that that arrived after the crash was restored. Some very old emails also seem to be fine.

This problem effects search - the results listed show the emails I want to find, but clicking on them opens different emails.

Refreshing the inbox hasn't helped. This does not seem to be a problem when I use my provider's webmail.

Is there a way to force evolution to re-index it's internal database? Or could one particular message be a problem?

I'm on Ubuntu Studio 21.10, using the latest Evolution from the default repos.

Comment: Hello. As you have written this is an issue you bring up the your Email folks. Has nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Evolution is a Gnome project?

Comment: How does that make it a Ubuntu OS issue, it does not. Good Luck.

Comment: There's more: If you're using IMAP which is almost certain in this day and age, then what's being shown depends entirely on the remote servers so nothing to do with the local client.

Comment: Y'all, if you take a sysadmin-or-GTFO approach, this is actively harmful to the Ubuntu ecosystem, which is intended to be one that is more accessible.  Evolution ships with Ubuntu and is part of the linux-on-the-desktop experience.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:

[Answer on linuxfoundation.org forums](https://forum.linuxfoundation.org/discussion/860119/email-list-pane-shows-duplicate-from-and-subject-but-different-messages)

I had the same problem with Evolution 3.46.4 on Fedora.

Given an inbox with messages:

From Bob, Message 1
From Clark, Message 2
From Tom, Message 3

If you click on message 2, you'd see the detail for message 3.

The poster on the link above suggested deleting the directory $HOME//.cache/evolution such as $HOME/maxwell/.cache/evolution

I did:

1. Quit evolution
2. $ cd $HOME     (starting a terminal you should be there already)
3. $ cd .cache    (in terminal)
4. $ ls -ld evolution    (just to see it exists)
5. $ rm -fr evolution  (to remove it)
6. I optionally used the kill command to kill a few background evolution processes but this is probably optional.
7. Restart evolution
8. Click on any message and problem is solved.